# regular travel from Frankfurt to Schwalbach am Tanus (nord)

Tags: trains, public-transport, germany, frankfurt

I am planning to take a job that is based in Schwalbach am Tanus (nord) area. However, I want to live in Frankfurt city. What kind of travel pass (monthly/yearly) would be suitable for such a situation? Is there anything I could use within the Frankfurt city as well as to travel to and from Schwalbach?

Or is there some place in between where I could live and utilize a travel pass?

Comment: Looks like you need a ticket for price category 4 https://www.vgf-ffm.de/fileadmin/VGF/Tickets__Tarife__Plaene/Fahrpreise/Documents/Kachel_Preise___Tarife_Preisstufenmatrix.pdf

Comment: That would be 140 EUR per month https://www.vgf-ffm.de/fileadmin/VGF/Tickets__Tarife__Plaene/Fahrpreise/Documents/Kachel_Preise___Tarife_Preisstufen___Preisliste_2020.pdf

Comment: @BernhardDöbler can you write that in an answer? It seems you know what you are talking about.

Comment: Don't forget to check with your employer if they offer a reduced price "Job Ticket". It's quite common for larger companies.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you maybe add a screenshot or tell the German name/category for this ticket? I couldn't figure it out from the german document. Also, to confirm, this will be valid throughout Hessen? @BernhardDöbler

Comment: @asdfex Could you tell me more about the Job Ticket? Is it a pass by RMV but like the company pays some part of it?

Comment: @x89 Yes, exactly. It's just like a regular monthly ticket, but based on a contract between a company and RMV. So you can't apply for this yourself, but the company (if it's a larger one, >100 people or so) might already have a contract for all its employees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Bernhard Döbler  has already pointed out this a regular RMV connection. Weekly ticket is 41 Euro, monthly is 140 Euro and yearly is 1377 Euro.

Try https://www.rmv.de/c/en/homepage and poke in your details.

From Frankfurt Main Station take the S3 (S-Bahn, local train). It goes every 30 minutes and takes about 20 minutes to Schwalbach Nord.

If you want to live in Frankfurt, picking something close to an S3 station can save a you lot of commuting time .

Comment: The S3 runs every 30 minutes.

Comment: The search results weren't saved so I am not sure what the link suggests. Could you maybe add a screenshot or tell the German name/category for this ticket? Also, to confirm, this will be valid throughout Hessen?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I fixed them both

Comment: Do you know whether this ticket is valid throughout Hessen?

Comment: It's not valid over all of Hessen, just whatever the RMV considers to be "Preisstufe 4" which is "price level 4". They have a map, but I find it to be unreadable. The RMV doesn't extend all the way to Nordhessen anyway. HIghest price level is 7 and a yearly ticket is about twice as expensive than level 4.